# Using Selenium, PhantomJS and Tor in python

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, tor

I'm trying to use phantomJS with selenium and Tor. I have the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
service_args = [
        '--proxy=127.0.0.1:9050',
        ' --proxy-type=socks5',
    ]
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args = service_args)
```

Every time I try to connect, I get the following error message:

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-98e27eb2ae26> in <module>()
  4             ' --proxy-type=socks5',
  5     ]
----> 6 driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args = service_args)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs    /webdriver.pyc in __init__(self, executable_path, port, desired_capabilities,    service_args, service_log_path)
 49         self.service = Service(executable_path, port=port,
 50             service_args=service_args, log_path=service_log_path)
---> 51         self.service.start()
 52 
 53         try:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.pyc in start(self)
 83         count = 0
 84         while True:
---> 85             self.assert_process_still_running()
 86             if self.is_connectable():
 87                 break

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.pyc in assert_process_still_running(self)
 96             raise WebDriverException(
 97                 'Service %s unexpectedly exited. Status code was: %s'
---> 98                 % (self.path, return_code)
 99             )
100 

WebDriverException: Message: Service phantomjs unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 255
```

PhantomJS and Selenium work fine with the Tor parameters. Any help to get this working would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This is an old one, but I came here, because I searched for exactly what you wanted to do.

When I executed your code, I got exactly the same behaviour.

Simply remove the blank space at second argument ('--proxy-type=socks5') and your code is working nicely.

Thus,

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    service_args = [
        '--proxy=127.0.0.1:9050',
        '--proxy-type=socks5',
    ]
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args = service_args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your exact phantomjs path?

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=<your_phantomjs_path>, service_args = service_args)
```